# Act depending on class instance

Tags: java, oop, inheritance

I have a `ClassB` inherited from `ClassA`. `ClassA` has a nested `ClassC` with a `methodA()` in it. In this `methodA()` I need to do things depending on condition if the outer class ClassA or ClassB. What is the best way to construct `if/else` statement? Thank you.

Comment: Sounds like a crime against inheritance.  I'd think about AOP before doing this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would better add some virtual methodB in ClassA and override it in ClassB, and call it in methodA of classC.

Comment: Or you can go further and implement Strategy pattern.

Comment: Just one caveat - all methods are "virtual" by default in Java, so there's no `virtual` keyword in the language.

Comment: But it depends on your needs and my approach can also take place in your case.

Comment: @moonwave99 sorry for missing this fact, I'm a C# guy :)

Answer (score 1):

This is not how OOP works - what if someones extends `ClassB` to `ClassD` and you want to further change behavior?

Anyway, [`instanceof`](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Language-Basics/FindingOutofwhatClassanObjectisInstantiated.htm) keyword may help you while you refactor your code.

Remember that one of the purposes of inheritance / interfaces and so is to prevent big chains of if/else statements - hiding them into methods won't help getting your code smoother.

Comment: What shall I do instead? Can I override the `methodA()`?

Comment: It really depends on what all these classes and method do, there's no jolly solution.

Comment: I would better add some virtual methodB in ClassA and override it in ClassB, and call it in methodA of classC.

Comment: Sounds good, Vitaliy, please answer and I'll accept your solution.